Minimum set of eigenvalues to uniquely label an irrep of $S_n$
The irreps of $S_n$ can be labeled by the eigenvalues of class operators $C_\mu$, where $\mu \vdash n=(\mu_1,\mu_2,\ldots)$ is a cycle class of $S_n$ elements, with $C_\mu$ defined by [1]
$$
C_\mu = \sum_{\sigma\in g_\mu}\sigma
$$
where $\sigma$ is a permutation with cycle class $\mu$, and $g_\nu$ is the set of permutations with cycle class $\mu$. (For shorthand, we can abbreviate $\mu$ by leaving off an ones, since they are implied by the constraint $\sum_i \mu_i=n$. This means that, in $S_5$, $(2,1,1,1)$ is written as $(2)$.)  Thus, for example, we can define
\begin{gather}
C_{(2)} = \sum_{i < j}^n (ij)
\\
C_{(3)} = \sum_{i<j<k}^n (ijk) + (ikj)
\\
C_{(2,2)} = \sum_{i<j<k<l}^n (ij)(kl) + (ik)(jl) + (il)(jk)
\end{gather}
The eigenvalues of these class operators are given by
$$
\lambda_{\mu}^{\nu} = \frac{\mathrm{order}(g_\mu)}{\mathrm{dim}(\nu)} \chi_{\mu}^{\nu}
$$
where $\mathrm{order}(g_\mu)$ is the order of the cycle class $\mu$, $\mathrm{dim}(\nu)$ is the dimension of the $S_n$ irrep $\nu \vdash n$, and $\chi_{\mu}^{\nu}$ is the simple character of $S_n$.
First, I believe the set of all $\lambda_\mu^{\nu}$ is sufficient to uniquely label $\nu$, though I don't actually have a proof; I suspect it has to do with the orthogonality of the simple characters.
Second, it is known that the eigenvalues $(\lambda_{(2,1^{n-2})},\lambda_{(2,1^{n-3})},\ldots,\lambda_{(2)})$ for the canonical group chain $S_n \supset S_{n-1} \supset \cdots \supset S_2$ can be put into a bijection with Young tableaux, and thus form a complete set of labels for every basis vector in every irrep. This means that one needs at most $n-1$ eigenvalues, I think.
Question: Is the set of eigenvalues $\{\lambda_{(i)}^\nu | 2 \leq i \leq n\}$ sufficient to uniquely label the irrep $\nu$?
By brute-force enumeration, I know:

$S_2\text{-}S_5$,$S_7$: one needs only $\lambda_{(2)}^\nu$ to uniquely label the irrep $\nu$.
$S_6,S_{8}\text{-}S_{14}$: one needs both $\lambda_{(2)}^\nu$ and $\lambda_{(3)}^\nu$ to uniquely label the irrep $\nu$.
$S_{15}\text{-}S_{23},S_{25},S_{26},S_{29}$: one needs all of $\lambda_{(2)}^\nu$, $\lambda_{(3)}^\nu$, $\lambda_{(4)}^\nu$ to uniquely label the irrep $\nu$.
$S_2\text{-}S_{25}$: the set $\lambda_{(2)}^\nu,\lambda_{(3)}^\nu,\ldots,\lambda_{(n)}^\nu$ is sufficient (but not necessarily necessary) to uniquely label the irrep $\nu$.


Related: Eigenvalues of operator on $S_n$'s group algebra
[1]: Group Representation Theory for Physicists, Chen, Ping, & Wang (2002)

Is $g_\mu$ standard notation?

Not sure... I've also seen it used as the order itself. Do you have a better notation for the cycle class itself (set of group elements)?

No. I suggest you [edit] the question to include the definition, just to be sure. Then again, I don't know enough representation theory . . .

Assuming you are working over $\mathbb C$ (or any field of characteristic zero in fact) the character $\chi^{\nu}$ of the irreducible $\nu$ determines it uniquely. Now if we set $o(\mu):=\text{order}(g_\mu)$, then the $o(\mu)$ are straight-forward to calculate directly, so knowledge of the $(\lambda_{mu}^{\nu})$ for all $\mu$ and fixed $\nu$ is equivalent to knowing $$
\frac{\lambda^{\nu}_{\mu}}{o(\mu)} = \frac{\chi^{\nu}_{\mu}}{\dim(\nu)} = \frac{\chi^{\nu}_{\mu}}{\chi^{\nu}_e},
$$
where $e$ denotes the identity element of the symmetric group $S_n$ (since the character of the identity element is the dimension of the representation).
Knowledge of $(\lambda^{\nu}_{\mu})_{\mu \vdash n}$ is thus equivalent to knowing $\chi^{\nu}$ up to a positive scalar, but the fact that characters are orthonormal allows you to recover that scalar, hence the scalars $(\lambda_{\mu}^\nu)_{\mu \vdash n}$ determine $\nu$ uniquely.
Addendum:
I think your claim about the eigenvalues $\lambda_{2,1^{n-2}}, \lambda_{2,1^{n-3}}, \ldots, \lambda_{(2)}$ for the canonical chain $S_n \supseteq S_{n-1}\supseteq \ldots \supseteq S_2$ being in bijection with Young Tableaux may be a slight misunderstanding -- it is, at least, so brief a remark that it may help to elaborate on it: there is a beautiful connection between standard Young Tableaux and the spectrum of a commutative algebra, but it does not come from the eigenvalues of the action of the class sums, but from a maximal abelian subalgebra $\mathcal A_n$ of $\mathbb C[S_n]$ which you can define recursively as follows:
For $n=1$ we let $\mathcal A_1 = \mathbb C[S_1]= \mathbb C$ since $S_1$ is the trivial group. Note suppose we have defined $\mathcal A_{n-1}\subseteq \mathbb C[S_{n-1}]$ an algebra with generators ($L_1=1$), $L_2,\ldots,L_{n-1}$, and consider $\mathbb C[S_{n-1}] \subseteq \mathbb C[S_n]$. Let $L_n = \sum_{j=1}^{n} (j n)$ be the sum of all transpositions with $n$ in their support. Then it is easy to see that $L_n$ commutes with $\mathbb C[S_{n-1}]$: indeed if $\sigma \in S_{n-1}$ then
$$
\sigma L_n \sigma^{-1} = \sum_{j=1}^{n-1} \sigma(j,n) \sigma^{-1} \sum_{j=1}^{n-1} (\sigma(j),n) = L_n
$$
It follows that setting $\mathcal A_n$ to be the subalgebra of $\mathbb C[S_n]$ generated by $\mathcal A_{n-1}$ and $L_n$ we obtain an abelian subalgebra of $\mathbb C[S_n]$ generated by $n-1$ elements: $\{L_2,\ldots,L_n\}$. It is the spectrum of the operators $\{L_2,\ldots,L_n\}$ on the irreducible representations of $\mathbb C[S_n]$ which yields the connection to Young Tableaux, not the spectrum of the $g_\mu$s, although the two are closely connected -- the centre of $\mathbb C[S_n]$ - which is spanned by the class sums $g_{\mu}$ -- is exactly given by the symmetric polynomials in the $\{L_i: 2\leq i \leq n\}$, and the algebras $\mathcal A_n$ are generated by centres of all the subalgebras $\mathbb C[S_k]$ ($k\leq n$) is the algebra $\mathcal A_n$. The elements $L_k$ have been discovered by various people independently, but are often known as "Jucys-Murphy" elements.

That is a good way of proving the statement that knowing $\lambda_\mu$ for all $\mu\vdash n$ is sufficient for uniqueness. I'm not sure if that helps with trying to use just those $\lambda_\mu^\nu$ where $\nu$ takes the form $(k)$ [or equivalently $(k,1^{n-k})$.

I've edited the question with some more brute-force results, so maybe it's clearer what I'm looking to prove.

Your update is interesting. I've been working with the eigenfunction method for representation theory which in fact constructs all of the representation theory via the class algebra. In that case, instead of the Jucys-Murphy elements, one uses the class operators to construct the Young-Yamanouchi basis. That's why I'm trying to find a minimal complete set of commuting operators which can be used to label $S_n$ irreps.

In particular, one uses the class operators of a canonical group chain to form a complete set of commuting operators (the CSCO-II) to completely determine a basis for an irrep.
